# VRRP or Carp in Cisco 1900 Series

Tags: cisco, routing, router, vrrp, fhrp

I'm planning to set up a dynamic route between pfSense and Cisco 1900 series.
First, I want to set up hardware redundancy. In pfSense, I'm using CARP and everything works.

My question is: Does the Cisco series 1900 support VRRP? Has anyone tried to setup hardware redundancy with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cisco supports VRRP. Cisco maintains many documents regarding this, e.g. [*First Hop Redundancy Protocols Configuration Guide, Cisco IOS Release 15M&T*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipapp_fhrp/configuration/15-mt/fhp-15-mt-book/fhp-vrrp.html):

> ### Enabling VRRP
>
> **SUMMARY STEPS**
>
> 1. **enable**
> 2. **configure terminal**
> 3. **interface** *type number*
> 4. **ip address** *ip-address mask*
> 5. **vrrp** *group* **ip** *ip-address* [**secondary**]
> 6. **end**
> 7. **show vrrp** [**brief**] | *group*]
> 8. **show vrrp interface** *type number* [**brief**]

VRRP is configured much the same way that HSRP is configured in your router.

Comment: Thank you. i just tested hsrp and i see that configuration is not duplicated in to the standby router. but this solution can help me.